# How to start a new activity and hide login page after successful login in android facebook app and get logout button on new page

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication

I am integrating facebook app with my android app and I don't want to perform default behaviour of  android facebook app i.e after successful login I don't want to come back on same login page and get the logout button there.
After successful login it quickly start a new activity having logout button there and login page doesn't appear on return back from login. Here is my main activity Java class code:

```
package com.example.facebook;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private LoginButton loginBtn;
    private Button postImageBtn;
    private Button updateStatusBtn;

    private TextView userName;

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

    private static String message = "Sample status posted from android app";
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    

        userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                if (user != null) {
                    
                    userName.setText("Hello, " + user.getName());
                } else {
                    userName.setText("You are not logged");
                }
            }
        });
        
        

        postImageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        postImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                postImage();
            }
});

        updateStatusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_status);
        updateStatusBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        buttonsEnabled(false);
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                buttonsEnabled(true);
                 if (Session.getActiveSession() != null || Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()){
                     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,nextscreen.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
        
        
                Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session opened");
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                buttonsEnabled(false);
                
                Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session closed");
            }
        }
    };

    public void buttonsEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    
        postImageBtn.setEnabled(isEnabled);
        updateStatusBtn.setEnabled(isEnabled);
    }

    public void postImage() {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            Request uploadRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), img, new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Photo uploaded successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                });
            uploadRequest.executeAsync();
        } else {
            requestPermissions();
}
    }

    public void postStatusMessage() {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), message,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            if (response.getError() == null)
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Status updated successfully",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermissions() {
        Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (s != null) {
            return s.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
        } else
            return false;
    }

    public void requestPermissions() {
        Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (s != null)
            s.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                    this, PERMISSIONS));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    //  buttonsEnabled(Session.getActiveSession().isOpened());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //  Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if (Session.getActiveSession() != null || Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()){
         //    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,nextscreen.class);
          //  startActivity(i);
      //  }
        
        
        
    }
    

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    }

}
```

after applying  activity(intent) in `if (state.isOpened())` method it return me on login page having logout button for a while and then jump on a new activity by own. But I don't want that. I want to return on a new activity having logout button there and don't want to show login page again and on click of logout button on new activity, I want login page.

Comment: did you tried calling finish(); right after the startActivity on sucessfull login . and add a button where you want to and on logout command start and activity which will take you back to the login activity ....

Comment: finish(); does't effect on my previous output.means does not fullfill my requirement. and also i want default logout button on new activity same  as this appear in login page by default. please suggest something else but anyways thanks for your quick help.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook login button if you success login. It will change the wording from "Log In Facebook" to "Logout". If you don't want to see that, just setVisibility GONE or Intent to desired activity. If you using intent, set the flag like below

```
Intent next = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
next.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(next);
```

Below is the example of facebook loginbutton

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), (object, response) -> {
                    // hide this facebook login button
                    // Intent to your desired activity

                });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,birthday,gender,first_name,last_name");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Message.LOGINCANCEL, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Message.LOGINFAILED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

If you want to change the "Logout" facebook button to "Log in Facebook" use below code. Just create BUtton and do onClick() to trigger below code

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null && com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null){
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue and not able to find any solution till date. But I am using workaround there. I am showing the ProgressDialog on Facebook callback method, so user can at least understand some thing is happing when login activity load again after Facebook successful login.

Below are the code:-

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {

    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");

        //------ Show loading progress
        ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginPopup.this, "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutLoginPopup);
        layout.setEnabled(false);
        LinearLayout layout_LayoutLogin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutLogin);
        layout_LayoutLogin.setEnabled(false);
        //------ End Show loading progress
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
                    // handleError(error, true);
                    return;
                }

                if (user != null) {
                    // Display the parsed user info
                    buildUserInfoDisplay(user, response, bar);

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to login");
                    bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Utils.showAlert(LoginPopup.this, "Message",
                            "Failed to login!");
                }

            }
        }).executeAsync();

    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        // Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Logged out...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        // .show();
    }

    //------ Hide loading progress
    //ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginPopup.this, "", "Loading...", true);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutLoginPopup);
    layout.setEnabled(true);
    LinearLayout layout_LayoutLogin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutLogin);
    layout.setEnabled(true);
    //------ End Hide loading progress
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was store a file that contains a value called isLoggedIn on the device using sharedPreferrences. When the user logs in, I set this value to true and then clear the value when he/she presses the loggout button. So anytime I start my app, I first check if the value is true. If true, move to the next activity, else, stay on the login page.

Still trying to figure out how to solve the problem in a professional way. All the best.